# Stripes Injection Enricher: can't connect to ejb module

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, javabeans, stripes

I got Java EE project. In the ejb module I have this class

```
@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class TestBean implements Test{

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "-----")
EntityManager em = null;

public Manager findByName(String name) {
    Manager manager = em.createNamedQuery("Manager.findByName", Manager.class).
            setParameter("name", name).getSingleResult();

    return manager;
}
```

}

In web module I have this class:

```
public abstract class BaseActionBean implements ActionBean  {

private MyActionBeanContext context;

@EJB
public TestBean wrapper;


public MyActionBeanContext getContext() {
    return context;
}

public void setContext(ActionBeanContext context) {
    this.context = (MyActionBeanContext) context;
}
}
```

In web.xml file I have this:

```
<init-param> 
        <param-name>Extension.Packages</param-name> 
        <param-value>
           com.samaxes.stripes.inject
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
```

But when I want to use this wrapper I got 'null'. 
stipes version 1.5.7   stripes-injection-enricher-1.0.3(this libraries added to web module)
How can I inject to my EJB module? please help

Comment: Injection is only supported in specific EE classes that are created by the container.  What is the concrete class of BaseActionBean, and how is that object created?  It will need to be a servlet, managed bean, CDI bean, another EJB, etc., and not an instance you created directly.

Comment: @bkail what if  BaseActionBean will extend HttpServlet it will work?

Comment: @samaxes can you help me,please

Comment: @bkail here is the short explanation : https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/display/STRIPES/Stripes+Injection+Enricher

Comment: Sorry, I have no familiarity with this stripes injection framework, so I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included stripes jar in ejb module and then wrote mappedName to ejb class

```
@EJB(mappedName = "java:global/project-name/project-name-ejb/TestBean")
public TestBean testBean;
```

Now it works